# change recent posts based on category

Tags: categories, wp-query

I am writing a code to display the recent posts of different categories. On clicking category 1, I want to display the recent posts from cat1 and on clicking cat 2 the recent posts from cat2 and so on.

The code I have written was displaying the same posts on **all** cats.

What should I do?

```
 <?php  
$rPosts = new WP_Query();
$rPosts->query('showposts=4&category_name=category1');

while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post(); ?>

    <h4><a href="#">POSTS FROM THIS CAT</a></h4>
    <p><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(300,221)); ?> </p>
    <h3><a href="#"><?php echo get_the_title();?></a></h3>
    <p><a class="btn btn-white" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read Full Story</a></p>

<?php 
endwhile; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're always displaying the posts from the category "category1" because that's what you've written in your code here `$rPosts->query('showposts=4&category_name=category1');`

If you want to just go to the category archive pages you can do that by generating the links with [get_term_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link). This function goes at the position where you're displaying the links & then this code is not needed. If not that please give us more details about where you're displaying the links & how exactly you want it to work

As a side note "showposts" is deprecated, please use "posts_per_page" instead